# MySQL many-to-many relation slow on big table

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many

I have 2 tables which are connected with a relationship table.

More details about the tables:

- **stores** (Currently 140.000 rows)

`id (index)
store_name
city_id (index)
...`

- **categories** (Currently 400 rows)

`id (index)
cat_name`

- **store_cat_relation**

`store_id
cat_id`

Every store belongs in one or more categories.

In the store_cat_relation table, I have indexes on (store_id, cat_id) and (cat_id, store_id).

I need to find the total amount of let's say supermarkets (cat_id = 1) in Paris (city_id = 1). I have a working query, but it takes too long when the database contains lots of stores in Paris or the database has lots of supermarkets.
This is my query:

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stores s, store_cat_relation r WHERE s.city_id = '1' AND r.cat_id = '1' AND s.id = r.store_id`

This query takes about 0,05s. Database contains about 8000 supermarkets (stores with category 1) and about 8000 stores in Paris (store_id = 1). Combined 550 supermarkets in Paris at the moment.

I want to reduce the query time to below 0,01s because the database is only getting bigger.

The result of EXPLAIN is this:

```
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: store_cat_relation
type: ref
possible_keys: cat_id_store_id, store_id_cat_id
key: cat_id_store_id
key_len: 4
ref: const
rows: 8043
Extra: Using index
***************************************
id: 1
select_type: SIMPLE
table: stores
type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY, city_id
key: PRIMARY
key_len: 4
ref: store_cat_relation.store_id
rows: 1
Extra: Using index condition; Using where
```

Anyone an idea why this query takes so long?

EDIT: I also created a SQL fiddle with 300 rows per table. With low amount of rows, it's quite fast, but I need it to be fast with +100.000 rows.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/675a3/1

Comment: What are the data types of your key columns, from your query it looks like they're some sort of string

Comment: Well then your query should be 
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stores s, store_cat_relation r WHERE s.city_id = 1 AND r.cat_id = 1 AND s.id = r.store_id
(or the parameterized equivalent). You're forcing the DBMS to coerce both the string and int to floating points on every comparison.

Comment: But that is almost certainly not the performance problem.

Comment: Thanks, learned something new! :) But you're right, this is not the performance problem because the query is again about 0,05s.

Comment: can you give some sample data to test ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen yes that's possible. How should I deliver it?

Comment: @OsiriX - best is SQL file with create over sqlfiddle.com or send it to me by email

Comment: @BerndBuffen I've created this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/675a3/1 but only with about 300 rows per table. Now it's quite fast, but with +100.000 rows per table, it's not anymore.

Comment: @OsiriX - i will generate some test data. the data from you is not much, because the optimizer nows that there is only one store and dont use a index. i will answer a little bit later

Comment: Thanks @BerndBuffen looking forward to it! As you can see below, Norbert made a suggestion for a new index on stores, which reduced the query time. Do you think it's possible to reduce it even further?

Comment: @OsiriX - short question - if the table are most read ? i have tested to create a 3 table like CREATE TABLE `city_cat` (
  `city` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `cat` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `anz` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city`,`cat`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; which holds all result

Comment: @OsiriX - and one more :-) - you say you have 140.000 rows in table store and only 400 in table categories. if sores.id not a unique id ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen, A new table is also a solution I have thought about and is probably the fastest for reads. But I thought this is a bad database design because every store_id has a single city_id so it's very easy to join. I might be wrong? :) And yes, it's mostly reads, the tables are updated when new stores are added/updated. The column id in table stores is indeed unique. But every store_id can have multiple categories.

Answer (score 3):

i have made some test and the best performance is to use the **Query cache**. You can enable them and use it **ON DEMAND**. so you can say which query are insert into the cache. if you want to use it you must make the changes in the /etc/my.cnf to make them persistent. If you change the tables you can also run some queries to warm up the cache

**Here a Sample**

**Table size**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> select count(*) from stores;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 10000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1 min 23.50 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]> select count(*) from store_cat_relation;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
| 10000000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.45 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

**Verify cache is on**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| have_query_cache | YES   |
+------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

**set cache size and on DEMAND**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SET GLOBAL query_cache_size = 1000000;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]> SET GLOBAL query_cache_type=DEMAND;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

**Enable Profiling**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> set profiling=on;
```

**First execute your query - takes 0.68 sec**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM stores s, store_cat_relation r WHERE s.city_id = '1' AND r.cat_id = '1' AND s.id = r.store_id;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      192 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.68 sec)
```

**now get it from cache**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT SQL_CACHE COUNT(*) FROM stores s, store_cat_relation r WHERE s.city_id = '1' AND r.cat_id = '1' AND s.id = r.store_id;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      192 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**see the Profile with duration in uS**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> show profile;
+--------------------------------+----------+
| Status                         | Duration |
+--------------------------------+----------+
| starting                       | 0.000039 |
| Waiting for query cache lock   | 0.000008 |
| init                           | 0.000005 |
| checking query cache for query | 0.000056 |
| checking privileges on cached  | 0.000026 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000014 |
| checking permissions           | 0.000025 |
| sending cached result to clien | 0.000027 |
| updating status                | 0.000048 |
| cleaning up                    | 0.000025 |
+--------------------------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.05 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

Comment: Thanks for the post. I have tested it and it works very nice. I didn't thought about it earlier, but I'm actually doing very small updates to the stores table very often (10+ times per minute). So the cache is flushed each time. When a visitor opens a "store-page", I'm increasing the 'hits' for that store by 1 in that table. As I'm doing ORDER BY hits a lot, I thought it's best to keep this hits column inside the stores-table. I'll see if I can move this column to somewhere else and maintain the performance. If I'm able to do that, I think Norbert's and your solution combined is perfect! :)

Comment: If you write often to these or the new table it is better to use InnoDB storage engine. InnoDB supports row lock, that means that only one row will be locked and MyISAM has only a table lock. When you update one row no other client can read the table and must wait for finish the update

Comment: Yeah it's a trade-off. The stores table was InnoDB before, but from tests I noticed that it was better to move to MyISAM because of lots of select queries. And also since a few weeks a fulltext index on one of the columns. But because 'hits' is just an indication to place the most popular stores at the top of the results, it might be better to move this to a new InnoDB table. And then maybe update the hits column inside the stores table once a week at night.

Comment: InnoDB has also a fulltext index and it is allways better to use innodb. You can also use MySQL prepared statements then the Optimizer looks only one time for the best way and not on every query. When you have many more row in your table you can use partitioning for the tables ie. on city, so internal the have his own index for each partition and the usage ist normal. Take also a look in your my.cnf if you have enabled innodb_file_per_table

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking at is index scenarios:

> Using the optimizer a DBMS tries to find the optimal path to the data. Depending on the data itself, this can lead to different access paths depending on the conditions (WHERE/JOINS/GROUP BY, sometimes ORDER BY) supplied. The data distribution in this can be key to fast queries or very slow queries.

So you have at this moment 2 tables, `store` and `store_cat_relation`. On store you have 2 indexes:

- id (primary)
- city_id

You have a where on city_id, and a join on id. The internal execution in the DBMS engine is then as follows:

1) Read index city_id
2) Then read table (ok, primary key index) to find id
3) Join on ID

This can be a bit more optimized with a multi column index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nn_1 ON store(city_id,id);
```

This should result in:

1) Read index idx_nn_1
2) Join using this index idx_nn_1

You do have fairly lob sided data in your current example with all `city_id=1` in your example. This kind of distribution of the data in the real data, can give you problems since `where city_id=` is then similar to saying "Just select everything from table store". The histogram information on that column can result into a different plan in those kind of cases, however if your data distribution is not so lob sided, it should work nicely.

On your second table `store_cat_relation` you might try an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_nn_2 ON store_cat_relation(store_id,cat_id);
```

To see if the DBMS then decides that leads to a better data access path.

With every join you see, study the join and see if a multi column index can reduce the number of reads.

> Do not index all your columns: Too many columns in an index will lead to slower inserts and updates.
>
> Also some scenarios might require you to create indexes in different order, leading to many indexes on a table (one with column(1,2,3), the next with column(1,3,2), etc). That is also not a real happy scenario, in which single column or a limitation of the columns and just reading the table for column 2,3 might be preferred.

Indexing requires testing your most common scenarios, which can be a lot of fun since you will see how a slow query running for seconds can suddenly run within 100s of seconds or even faster.

Comment: Norbert, thanks a lot! The new index stores(city_id,id) reduced the query time on the full table from 0,05s to 0,01s! That's a nice improvement. The new index on store_cat_relation you suggested was already in place, but not used by MySQL. I see it's used now. Again thanks a lot! I'll wait a little on Bernd Buffen's answer to see if he can improve even further before accepting this answer.